# value of $P''(1)$ in a degree $4$ of $P(x)$

Tags: calculus

> If $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $4$ with $P(2)=-1,P'(2)=0,P''(2)=2,P'''(2)=-12,P''''(2)=24.$ Then $P''(1)=$

What i try

Let $P(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$

So $P'(x)=4ax^3+3bx^2+2cx+d$

And so $P''(x)=12ax^2+6bx+2c$

And so $P'''(x)=24ax+6b$ and $P''''(x)=24a$

Put all values $P''''(2)=24a=24\Longrightarrow a=1$

$P'''(2)=24+6b=-12\Longrightarrow b=-6$

Same way to all calculate $c,d,e$

How do i solve it without such a long way

Please help me to solve in short way

Comment: What is $P'(2)=-0$? Isn't ${}=0$ enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**:

Remember Taylor's formula is an exact formula for polynomials (at order equal to the degree), so at order $4$:

\begin{align}P(x)&=P(2)+P'(2)(x-2)+P''(2)\frac{(x-2)^2}2+P'''(2)\frac{(x-2)^3}6+P^{(4)}(2)\frac{(x-2)^4}{24}\\
&=-1+(x-2)^2-2(x-2)^3+(x-2)^4.
\end{align}
whence $$P''(x)=2-12(x-2)+12(x-2)^2.$$

Comment: To @Bernard : $P''(2)=2$, so correct your answers for $P(x)$ and $P''(x)$. I can see some more typos...

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak Thanks for pointing the  typos! I shouldn't make calculations directly on screen Do you see any remaining typo?

Comment: you have $(x-3)^2$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

First, you have $\quad P'''(x) = 24ax + 6b \iff P'''(2) = 24a \cdot 2 + 6b = 48a + 6b$.

So, $\quad P'''(2) = -12 \iff 48a + 6b = -12 \iff 6b = -60 \iff b =-10$.

Next, $\quad P''(2) = 2 \iff 48 - 120 + 2c = 2 \iff c = 37$.

Next, $\quad P'(2) = 0 \iff 32 - 120 + 148 + d = 0 \iff d = -60$.

Finally, $P(2) = -1 \iff 16 - 80 + 148 - 120 + e = -1 \iff e = 35$.

$$$$

$P''(1) = 26$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Consider $Q(x) = P(x+2)$. What do you know about $Q$, given the properties of $P$?